# Thin Maximum connections meaning and the need of clusters?

Tags: ruby, nginx, thin

Thin maximum connection for Thin is set to 1024 and previous questions on stackoverflow clearly explain how to change that. My question is regarding a small ruby application. What does 1024 connections means in terms of users ? Is it 1024 concurrent users (I guess not but..) ?

Several tutorials provide instructions on setting up a cluster with a cluster of e.g. 3.
My question is in users/size of an application terms when is a cluster or 3 needed and the single mode with 1024  is no longer sufficient? I appreciate that it is hard to generalize and depends on the app I think that many ruby coders could benefit from some guidance on this.

This also links to another question: how does passenger compares like if you run your app with a standard passenger + nginx setup (or apache) what would be the equivalent in terms of performance if thin is used in stade of passenger e.g. how many thin servers etc.
Thanks in advance